# Scala: Use multiple constructors from Java in Scala

Tags: java, scala, constructor

I want to use a Jar in Scala, that is written in Java.

There are classes, that have multiple constructores, for example:

```
public LabeledDock(Parent<? super Labeled> parent, int index, Class<?> subtype){}
```

and

```
public LabeledDock(Parent<? super Labeled> parent, Class<?> subtype)
```

So the first constructor has 3 inputs, the second only 2 inputs.

If i want to use these constructors in Scala in that way:

```
val button = new LabeledDock(scene.asParent(), classOf[Button])
```

Scala tells me that *"ambiguous reference to overloaded definition"*

If i use

```
val button = new LabeledDock(scene.asParent(), 0, classOf[Button])
```

all works fine.
So i think with the first variable declaration Scala doesn't know which constructor he should use, because they are similar to each other. How can i use the constructor with only 2 inputs instead of adding the third input.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are there any more constructors for `LabeledDock`?

Comment: Yes, there are several more constructors. The problem always happened if i use a constructor that has only 2 parameters and is similar to another constructor (regarding to the input parameters)

Comment: Can you give a complete list of the constructors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, with the help from a workmate, i have solved that problem.

Instead of

```
classOf[Button]
```

i have to use

```
classOf[Button].asInstanceOf[Class[_]]
```

With this it works fine.