# Scala: generate class from a string

Tags: string, class, scala

I want to dynamically create a Class from a String.

The String has the exact name of the Class (by the way is a Java class)

For example

```
val classString = "gui.MainFrame"
```

I create the class with

```
val mainClass: Class[_] = Class.forName(classString)
```

Scala founds the class, but if i want to use this class for example with

```
AppExecutor.executeNoBlock(classOf[mainClass])
```

Scala tells me that type mainClass cannot be found.

If i use it in that way

```
AppExecutor.executeNoBlock(mainClass.asInstanceOf)
```

it says that *java.lang.Class cannot be cast to scala.runtime.Nothing$*
So how can i use this class now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"You're holding it wrong."

`classOf` accepts a type parameter and returns a `Class` object. You can't pass a `Class` object as a type parameter, hence the error.

Also, you already have your `Class` object in `mainClass`. If you want to necessarily use `classOf`, you can do this:

```
val mainClass = classOf[gui.MainFrame]
```

instead. But otherwise you should stick to your previous approach, i.e.:

```
val mainClass = Class.forName(classString)
```

If the code you're trying to use is `org.jemmy.fx.AppExecutor`, you can just invoke it directly with `mainClass`:

```
AppExecutor.executeNoBlock(mainClass.asInstanceOf[Class[_ <: javafx.application.Application]])
```

Since the method apparently has a qualified type parameter (i.e. not a normal wildcard `Class[_]`, or `Class<?>` in Java notation).

Comment: Yes you are right, i want to use the AppExecutor from Jemmy, and i know that i can call it directly with "mainClass", but the problem is, that the value of "mainClass" should not be the same every time. It should be variable, so that a user can enter another Class that is startet with AppExecutor. So i cannot use val mainClass = classOf[gui.MainFrame], because it would not be variable.

Comment: @AKR : like I said, you can still use `Class.forName(classString)` if that's the case, the problem was in how you invoked `executeNoBlock()`.

Comment: I tried it that way: "val mainClass = Class.forName(mainClassString)" and then "AppExecutor.executeNoBlock(mainClass)" but this leads to the error message "- overloaded method value executeNoBlock with alternatives: (x$1: Class[_ <: javafx.application.Application],x$2: <repeated...>[String])Unit <and> (x$1: Class[_ <: 
  javafx.application.Application])Unit cannot be applied to (Class[?0(in value <local $anon>)])"

Comment: @AKR. That's another story. Not sure if I got the cast correctly, but see my edit.

Comment: Yeah, haven't seen your edit ;) It works fine now, there was just a little failure in your expression. It has to be called like that: AppExecutor.executeNoBlock(mainClass.asInstanceOf[Class[_ <: javafx.application.Application]]). Now it works with the String, thank you!

Comment: @AKR : d'oh! You're right, I forgot to type in the full type, sorry about that (corrected now). BTW, generally, it's good practice to [accept the answer that helped you solve the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). And this applies to all question, for example, I see you've [self-answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337509/scala-use-multiple-constructors-from-java-in-scala/18339142#18339142) your other question - you should accept that answer as well. That way people know which answers help when they look for the same problem.

Comment: No problem. Thank you for your advice to accept the answer, i'm new to stackoverflow, so i haven't got all the features of this wonderful site now. ;)